# How to install fonts in Ubuntu 19.04 / LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, inkscape

I have a rather clean installation of Ubuntu 19.04 on which I have downloaded a Google font (TTF-format), opened it in Font Viewer, and clicked install. In Font Manager I now find the font listed under "User" (not under "System"). The font is also in my ~/.local/share/fonts folder. I am able to use the font in apps like GIMP.

However, apps like LibreOffice and Inkscape still don't show the font, not even after reboot. Does anyone know a solution for this? Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: try to rebuild the font cache with `fc-cache -f -v` and check that font files are readable for all `cd ~/.local/share/fonts ; chmod -R a+r *`

Comment: Two location where fonts usually are automatically visible in e.g. Firefox, LibreOffice : 1. `/usr/share/fonts/TTF`, and 2. `~/.fonts/`. ... ($ mkdir .fonts)

Comment: @KnudLarsen Copying the TTF files to `/usr/share/fonts/TTF` worked. I find it strange this workaround was necessary. Anyhow: many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two location where fonts usually are automatically visible in e.g. Firefox, LibreOffice :

1. `/usr/share/fonts/TTF/`, and
2. `~/.fonts/`
   Create the directory : `$ mkdir .fonts`

   `$ cp [font].ttf .fonts/`

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you install Synaptic Package Manager from Ubuntu Software and then install the font you want? You can then install fonts from Synaptic Package Manager.

Alternately, install font manager from Ubuntu software manager or using the command:
sudo apt install font-manager